Use sshpass for SSHFS with a proxy jump
I want to automatically mount an SSHFS directory with a proxy jump.
Initially, i mount my SSHFS like this :
sshfs -o ProxyJump=user_jump@jump_host user_final@final_host:/
How can i mount my SSHFS directory using a clear password for the jump and final user and sshpass ?
Note: For the jump host, I want to keep the -o ProxyJumpoption as using ssh_command="ssh -J jump_host"  does not work in my case.

Does this help? Also, would you consider public key authentication instead of password?
